# Problem with making a .exe without a console window (PyInstaller)

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging

I've made a executable of a python code, but everytime I run it, a console window opens. To stop that, I've tried:

- Running `--noconsole` while packaging
- changing the the `console=True` to `console=False` on the .spec file.

The first one doesn't work at all, nothing changes. When I do the second one, though, the .exe stops working (when I try to open, it doesn't).

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use either -w, --windowed, or --noconsole. I do not see a --nocommand option in the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options).

Comment: The second one won't work because it specifies that the finished python program shouldn't have a console window, not the pyinstaller process (to my knowledge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using pyinstaller to create an exe.

Just add --noconsole flag and the command window wont appear.

e.g.

pyinstaller --noconsole scriptname.py

As pointed out by author this works after changing to debug=True and console=False in spec file.

Comment: I've used --noconsole during packaging, it did not work.

Comment: You can also edit the .spec file. Edit the line to make sure (console=False). After that you can package like this - pyinstaller <your spec file>

Comment: The command I'm running is `python -m PyInstaller --name Gameficacao --noconsole path\Gameficacao\Gameficacao.py`.
I've tried to edit the spec file as well, like I said in the post, and I ran `python -m PyInstaller file.spec`, which gave me the problem I talked about on the post.

Comment: Try this: (pyinstaller --noconsole  path\Gameficacao\Gameficacao.py). I dont use name flag and assuming it to be a positional argument that comes later. Anyways you can rename the exe through windows explorer.

Comment: didn't work, same problem that I was having: the app doesn't open at all. Sorry

Comment: Then it might be an issue regarding hidden imports. Pyinstaller wouldn't have packed some library. You can do 2 things: a) add a debug (--debug flag) while creating exe this will show where its failing     b) In such cases, i call my exe from command prompt and it lists out the exact error which we can then resolve

Comment: I tried to run the command for debugging, but nothing changed again. Strangely though, when I changed debug=False to debug=True in the code and then packaged (while having the console set to False), it worked fine. Thanks mate. Please edit the answer to include this as the solution